# Values of java.util.Date objects mismatch with the ones generated by MongoDB Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, java.util.date

When I query the data through the a date field using `gt` & `lt` properties, values of `java.util.Date` objects **mismatch** with the ones in the generated MongoDB query which is provided by the **MongoDB Java driver**.

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder();
queryBuilder.put("publishDate").greaterThan(startDate);
queryBuilder.put("publishDate").lessThan(endDate);

// startDate: Wed Sep 07 23:00:00 EEST 2016
// startDate: Wed Sep 07 23:15:00 EEST 2016
// Generated query: { "publishDate" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : "2016-09-07T20:00:00.000Z"} , "$lt" : { "$date" : "2016-09-07T20:15:00.000Z"}} , "topic" : "#iPhone7" , "finalEmotion" : { "$exists" : true}}
```

As you can see above, the values in the generated query are 3 hours earlier than the actual ones.

**Edit:** Using `Calendar` instead of `Date` object:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startHour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Calendar calEnd = (Calendar) calendar.clone();
calEnd.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteRange);

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder();

queryBuilder.put("publishDate").greaterThan(calStart.getTime());
queryBuilder.put("publishDate").lessThan(calEnd.getTime());
queryBuilder.put("topic").is(topic);
queryBuilder.put("finalEmotion").exists(true);
```

Comment: you will need a calendar. Set to your timezone before querying. Date by design is UTC.

Comment: Can you provide the API related with it? Could not find any method to set the timezone of the query? @Veeram

Comment: I mean create a calendar object from date object you have and set the time zone on the calendar and use this object instead of date.

Comment: it is still same since at the end of the day, you have a date to be send to MongoDB & I do not have any issues with it. The issue is the way MongoDB Java driver handles it. I have created two calendars with setting the dates above, still there is 3 hours diff between them. You can post what you mean as answer if you think I do something wrong. @Veeram

Comment: It is updated. @Veeram

Comment: Can you try timezone EEST ?

Comment: still same @Veeram

Comment: I think the date you are seeing in the generated query is in UTC(Mongo Default) which is +3.00 for EEST.  Are your queries not coming back with results ? Btw after thinking it through your initial code with java.util.date should work and dont worry about the generated query dates as they are right.